# XmlNode.ReplaceChild is complaining that the node I'm trying to remove is not a child despite the fact that I got to the node via ParentNode

Tags: c#, xml

I have a simple function that's designed to copy a section of an xml document to another.  I want to replace one node with the other so ReplaceChild seems like the logical choice.  I keep getting the error 'The reference node is not a child of this node.' though.  That seems odd since I found that node by asking for the parent in the first place.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
    private static void KeepSection(XmlDocument newDoc, XmlDocument currentDoc, XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr, string path)
    {
        XmlNode section = currentDoc.SelectSingleNode(path, nsmgr);
        XmlNode newSection = newDoc.SelectSingleNode(path, nsmgr);
        if (newSection != null && section != null)
        {
            XmlNode parent = newSection.ParentNode;
            parent.ReplaceChild(newSection, newDoc.ImportNode(section, true));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you have your `ReplaceChild` parameters reversed:

```
public virtual XmlNode ReplaceChild(
    XmlNode newChild,
    XmlNode oldChild
)
```

Comment: I feel incredibly stupid after stumbling upon this. However, I think we can all agree that the parameter order seems counterproductive.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was being an idiot.  I got the parameters to ReplaceChild the wrong way around.  The code should have been,

```
            parent.ReplaceChild(newDoc.ImportNode(section, true), newSection);
```

Sorry about that!

Comment: I wouldn't say you were being an idiot - I think the parameter ordering is not intuitive.  :-)

Comment: ha! i just made the same mistake! lost a solid 10 minutes scratching my head.