# Append a XML node from another XML file using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, saml

I am trying to modify a XML file. I already delete the part of the XML that I do not need, but now I am trying to append a node from another XML file.

This is my code to delete the node 'saml:AssertionEncrypted' from the XML file:

```
XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
Doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
Doc.Load("XMLAssertionEncrypted.xml");

XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(Doc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
XmlNode node = Doc.SelectSingleNode("//saml:EncryptedAssertion", ns);

var list = Doc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("saml:EncryptedAssertion").OfType<XmlElement>().ToArray();

XmlNode root = Doc.DocumentElement;

foreach(var element in list) {
  var parent = element.ParentNode;
  if (parent != null) {
    parent.RemoveChild(element);
    //parent.ReplaceChild(newNodeElement, element); //This neither works
  }
}
```

Now, I want to add the whole Mytest.xml file into XMLAssertionEncrypted.xml, in the same position where was the node deleted before.

```
XmlDocument newNode = new XmlDocument();
xml.PreserveWhitespace = true;
xml.Load("Mytest.xml");
XmlNode newNodeElement = newNode.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/");

root.InsertAfter(newNodeElement, root.LastChild);
```

I am getting the error "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."

This is "xmlAssertionEncrypted.xml" once the node is removed:

```xml
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Version="2.0" ID="mReKMQjpJ81L9Yu" IssueInstant="2019-09-11T13:29:01.254Z" Destination="https://test.com/sso.aspx">
  <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">saml.test.com</saml:Issuer>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <ds:Reference URI="#mFCXf3nW6C7tzReKMQjpJ81L9Yu">
        <ds:Transforms>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /> </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <ds:DigestValue>hwFmHiMyh07qJB88=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue> 73Z/brHijqXg3sRQGsgeZlsnH5JyBj/ADJZgCablLXHBr75wQmZi1AvsLE9e/h3+U7RMalqqx0TI bo8OXA/9ZTdJnF9zWU9hYcFhHBTPF9fGDdsFIg== </ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
      <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate> MIIGojCCBYqgAwIBAgIQCEZjQ1QTXW74RfN6KsynzjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBEMQswCQYDVQQG EwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMR4wHAYDVQQDExVEaWdpQ2VydCBHbG9iYWwgQ0Eg RzIwHhcNMTkwMjAxMDAwMDAwWhcNMjEwMjAxMTIwMDAwWjB0MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzERMA8GA1UE bxAyKah48l0k7uCG4u+WOsvO9edQ+3WjLl7u7oneLqB2mXSccz545tUQJyTFZUVdaTI7E7cy
          vmHkx2ubL1gnvSAQ/h5huCoc4zoFHWLdkfDpJzYwjm/rXWfhanaxYlTlYb7ExD09RuUrMS0ahcLt K2nRAx7CD6oLdH6LTCuuZNaaQloK1QBRQWSr5X1Q5v56/VeMVEs8/qd/28y+a4G+Fg== </ds:X509Certificate>
      </ds:X509Data>
      <ds:KeyValue>
        <ds:RSAKeyValue>
          <ds:Modulus> QxcV+y50B1E+oV8oHD0c+ZTN1NRGWCfFLPoRhIShIG5QaPpQy1h9E74BO2VohQPhkj9hwRC7qTIb pKXztQi0T2BERs/iDxEEHa9xzY0AjBEqvUoZ8iqbd4IoqcF0+ryWwP+rCR9FPy43aW+U0mvYn2KT N+MA0JSdhLrAD9h1KKQIpXnL64W7QDexiJaXUQ== </ds:Modulus>
          <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
        </ds:RSAKeyValue>
      </ds:KeyValue>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
  <samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" /> </samlp:Status>
</samlp:Response>
```

And I would like to append the new XML node from "Mytest.xml" right after '/samlp:Status' and before '/samlp:Response'.

This is "Mytest.xml" file:

```xml
<saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="zrvyPwcFJXd5nKoaGoVP24Y_KYO" IssueInstant="2019-09-11T13:29:01.257Z" Version="2.0">
  <saml:Issuer>saml.test.com</saml:Issuer>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></ds:SignatureMethod>
      <ds:Reference URI="#zrvyPwcFJXd5nKoaGoVP24Y_KYO">
        <ds:Transforms>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></ds:DigestMethod>
        <ds:DigestValue>R2ho2iZU=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>
      051pdJAuf2oHLQQzWN1RW0KLwATj0MRfdy0TLg==
    </ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
      <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate>
          vmHkx2ubL1gnvSAQ/h5huCoc4zoFHWLdkfDpJzYwjm/rXWfhanaxYlTlYb7ExD09RuUrMS0ahcLt K2nRAx7CD6oLdH6LTCuuZNaaQloK1QBRQWSr5X1Q5v56/VeMVEs8/qd/28y+a4G+Fg==
        </ds:X509Certificate>
      </ds:X509Data>
      <ds:KeyValue>
        <ds:RSAKeyValue>
          <ds:Modulus>
            N+MA0JSdhLrAD9h1KKQIpXnL64W7QDexiJaXUQ==
          </ds:Modulus>
          <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
        </ds:RSAKeyValue>
      </ds:KeyValue>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
  <saml:Subject>
    <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">835</saml:NameID>
    <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
      <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2019-09-11T13:30:01.257Z" Recipient="https://test.com/sso.aspx"></saml:SubjectConfirmationData>
    </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
  </saml:Subject>
  <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2019-09-11T13:28:01.257Z" NotOnOrAfter="2019-09-11T13:30:01.257Z">
    <saml:AudienceRestriction>
      <saml:Audience>https://test.com</saml:Audience>
    </saml:AudienceRestriction>
  </saml:Conditions>
  <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2019-09-11T13:29:01.256Z" SessionIndex="P24Y_KYO">
    <saml:AuthnContext>
      <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </saml:AuthnContext>
  </saml:AuthnStatement>
</saml:Assertion>
```

Comment: Whatever you're trying to accomplish should be done via a SAML library. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57946037/how-to-decrypt-adfs-saml-response-in-net for suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrypt SAML Response with X.509 Certificate and Private Key in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982513/decrypt-saml-response-with-x-509-certificate-and-private-key-in-net)

Comment: Have you tried the answer to [XmlNode.ReplaceChild is complaining that the node I'm trying to remove is not a child despite the fact that I got to the node via ParentNode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1930680/3744182)?  On first look it seems to be a perfect duplicate.